# Search is broken in the "How to Ask"

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, asking-questions, help

If you happen to get to the ["How to Ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) (not to be confused with [help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), you'll notice a search box.  If you try a search, nothing much happens:

[image: Search is still searching.]

This happens even when you search for something reasonable like `sql` or `c++`. Interestingly, the [meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice) version of the page *does* produce results:

[image: Tada!]

A sampling of other sites (both main and meta) show it likely is failing most everywhere.

Comment: Same here. Error is `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getSidebarPopupOptions' of undefined "`

Comment: +1 for the contents of the search field :D (and for the good question in general)

Comment: Sometimes reproducible. I get it working intermittently. The auto-generating list sometimes doesn't pop up on its own, but if I hit the search button after entering my query, it'll display the results below. For some queries do have the results automatically show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build: 2014.3.6.2023 on MSO and 2014.3.6.1429 elsewhere.

Your sample question triggered the "your question appears to be subjective and will probably be closed" warning, which of course doesn't really apply to this page.

The subjectivity check also doesn't run on MSO and child meta sites, which is why you saw the same query work here.